# reusing the salt states in the AMI image

Tags: amazon-web-services, salt-stack

I have several salt states(base and pillars) already written and present in Amazon s3. I want to re-use the salt states instead of writing the salt state again. I want to create an AMI image using packer and apply the salt-states that I have downloaded from s3 to the Packer Builder EC2 instance. Even if the salt-minion is installed on the CentOS -7 machine, I have installed salt-master service as well and started both salt-minion and salt-master by following commands.

```
cat > /etc/salt/minion.d/minion_id.conf <<'EOT' id: ${host} # id salt-minion id EOT
```

Generate the name of the master to connect to

```
cat > /etc/salt/minion.d/master_name.conf <<'EOT' master: localhost EOT

systemctl enable salt-minion 
systemctl start salt-minion
systemctl enable salt-master
systemctl start salt-master
```

When running the below command it doesn't list any minions:

```
salt-key -L Accepted Keys: Denied Keys: Unaccepted Keys: Rejected Keys:
```

So the salt 'localhost-*' state.sls state.high_state
 fails with errors:

```
"No minions matched the target. No command was sent, no jid was assigned.
ERROR: No return received"
```

This is because no minionid is created from salt-key.

Anybody has any idea why the salt-key is not being shown with salt-minion and how can i resolve this issue by running the existing salt-state successfully downloaded from s3 will work in AMI image?

Regards 
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

What could be happening is that your `minions` can't find (resolve/DNS) the master [salt](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/index.html#minion-configuration).

What you could do is add the IP of your master to your minions `/etc/salt/minion` something like this:

```
master: 10.0.0.1
```

Replace `10.0.0.3` with the IP of your master

Later restart your `minion` and check the master again for requests.